# Source for yartzeit candle?

Tags: candle-lighting

What is the source for lighting a candle on the anniversary of someone's death (yartzeit candle)? What are the sources for lighting such a candle on other days such as Yom Kippur, Yom Tov etc?

Comment: I think this is two separate questions here. You might want to split the one about Yom Tov and Shabbat candles as a new question.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13500/759

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=560

Comment: @Scimonster I suspect "_yizkor_ candles" were the intent. But the asker would do well to [clarify](/posts/56523/edit) the question. In other news, I think this is probably a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13500.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the yahrtzeit candle comes from the metaphor in

> Proverbs 20:27:
>
> נֵ֣ר יְ֭הוָה נִשְׁמַ֣ת אָדָ֑ם חֹ֝פֵ֗שׂ כָּל־חַדְרֵי־בָֽטֶן׃
>
> The spirit of man is the lamp of the LORD, Searching all the inward parts.

Comment: Can you source this claim?

Comment: @DoubleAA - I believe that I have seen this in SA, but I have to locate it and edit later

Comment: Also Hlhow that verse is connected to the yearly marking of passing, and the holidays.

Comment: This is not found in Shulchan Aruch however it's mentioned by later achronim. It has no "real" makor and the custom is highly suspect....