# Source for Memorial Lights in Synagogue

Tags: halacha, minhag, sources-mekorot, lighting, yahrtzeit

What is the source for having memorial electric lights usually affixed to plaques that are found in many shuls to remember the *yahrtzeit* of relatives? Is this an old *minhag* or of relatively recent vintage?

Comment: I don't know. But this may help point you toward an answer: _Taame Haminhagim_, _kuntres acharon_ footnote 50 to 1071, page 482: "ובשם שו״ת כתב סופר סימן ס״ה כתב, שיותר טוב להדליקו בבית הכנסת" (though at least in the context of the _TH_ that's specific to שבת).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13500/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56523/759

Answer (score 2):

[Rav Shlomo Aviner at kipa.co.il](http://www.kipa.co.il/jew/53805.html) rejects a connection between the memorial lights in  shul and the נר של מתים mentioned in ברכות נג א and the נר יהא דלוק במקומו mentioned by רבי יהודה הנשיא in  כתובות קג.

Extract of the Hebrew Text below:

He says that the Rishonim (= leading rabbis who were deciders of Jewish law and lived between 1050 and 1500) wrote in the name of Rabeinu Osher (Orchos Chayim Hilchos Erev Yom Hakippurim 60 (11) Kolbo 68) [died in Toledo on 9 Cheshvan 5089 (1328 CE)], that the custom to light a light in synagogue before Yom Kippur for a departed parent is because it is an honour to Hashem as it says “with lights honour Hashem”. He adds that the reason is that the light is needed so that people can read all night.

That means that the reason that the light atones is because it allows people to pray and learn by its light and the merit of the prayers and learning will accrue to the merit of the departed. Rav Ben-zion Meir Chai Uziel, Rishon Letzion, [in 1939 appointed Chief Rabbi of Palestine] says the same about the lights lit in synagogue for the yahrtzeit.

> הראשונים כתבו בשם רבנו אשר שנוהגים להדליק בערב יום הכיפורים "נר או
>   פנס... לכפר על אביו ועל אמו כי כבוד הוא להשם יתברך, שנאמר 'באורים כבדו
>   ד''" (ארחות חיים הלכות ערב יום הכיפורים ס' י"א; כלבו סח), אך הוסיפו:
>   "לפי שצריכין לקרות בספר כל היום וכל הלילה תמיד... וזולת זה לא יראו
>   לקרות בלילות, ועוד נהגו בזה לכבוד השם ולכבוד בית הכנסת על דרך 'באורים
>   כבדו ד''" (כלבו שם).
>
> כלומר, הטעם שהדלקת הנר מכפרת היא משום שניתן להתפלל וללמוד לאורו, וזכות
>   התפילה והלימוד היא המביאה לעילוי נשמת הנפטר. וכתב על כך הראשון לציון
>   הגאון הרב בן-ציון מאיר חי עוזיאל: "ונרות שמדליקין ביום יארצייט הוא
>   לעילוי נשמה... והוא בכלל ברא מזכה אבא [=הבן מזכה את אביו], בפעולת מצוה
>   של הארת בית הכנסת שהוא לכבוד בית הכנסת, ולהאיר עיני הצבור בלמודם
>   ותפלתם שמתוך הספר..." (שו"ת משפטי עוזיאל ג או"ח ס' כג. ).

He concludes:

> לסיכום: נר נשמה או נר זיכרון אינם חובה ממש, אינם מצווה ואין להם מקור
>   קדום, אבל הדלקתם היא מנהג קדוש שהתקבל בעם ישראל

The yahrzeit light is not a real obligation, not a mitzva and it does not have an early source. But lighting it is a holy custom which has been accepted by the Jewish people.

I assume that the memorial light plaques are the modern equivalent of those lights lit in the shul for yahrtzeit or Yom Kippur.